# LED Backlight Strips on TV Causing External Speaker Interference

Tags: led, television, speakers, interference

I'm not sure if this is the correct place to post a question like this, but here we go.

I recently purchased some LED strips for some backlight on my TV. Admittedly, these backlights are of the "cheap Amazon purchase" variety (although not the absolute cheapest out there). The LED lights are powered by USB, which I have plugged in to the back of the television.

I also had some old-ish Klipsch speakers (two satellites and a subwoofer) that I decided to try to hook up to the TV as well. The speakers connect to the TV through an 3.5 mm AUX cord. However when the speakers are powered on and connected to the TV, I noticed that there is a high pitched buzzing coming from both satellite speakers. I can make the buzzing stop if I disconnect the LED lights from their USB power. Also, If I connect the LED strips to some USB power source other than the TV, I can have the lights on with no speaker interference. The problem with that however is that then the LED lights are always on - as opposed to when they are powered by the TV USB outlet, in which case the lights only turn on when the TV is powered on. Obviously the latter is much preferable.

And I'm not sure if this is relevant, but the TV and speakers are currently powered by different wall outlets.

[Here is the spec sheet for the speakers](https://d2um2qdswy1tb0.cloudfront.net/product-specsheets/Pro-Media-2.1-THX-Cert-Spec-Sheet.pdf?mtime=20181213080028&focal=none)

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you install the LED's and the speakers at the  same time or the speakers were working fine but the problem started with the addition of the LED's?   Are your speaker powered, if not there should be an amp between the TV and the speakers?  More details on your set up is needed. Are your speakers shielded?

Comment: I installed them at the same time, but the speakers work fine if the LED lights are unplugged. I'm not sure what you mean by "Are your speaker powered"...there is a power cord connected the subwoofer to a wall outlet, and then red/black wires running from the subwoofer to each satellite.

Comment: You are saying the aux cable goes to the sub first and then the speakers are wired from the sub?  Not knowing what sub you have i can not say if it powers the speakers as well, probably not, just passing the signal on. The Tv will not have the proper amplification (power) for the speakers, The sub has its own amp (i assume).  Passive speaker need a power source, an amp or A/V receiver, Powered speakers have amp built in  you plug them into a power source, wall outlet, like the sub. We can avoid assumptions if you post the make/model numbers of all the equipment and provide more details.

Comment: The usual (*proper for passive speakers*) set up is to send audio out from the TV to an Audio/Video  (*A/V*) unit,  OR Integrated amplifier. Then the audio is sent from the A/V - AMP  to the speakers/sub.  BUT, that is not to say that a proper set up will eliminate   interference from **cheap Chinese**  LED's. I have  I have an A/V set up and cheep LED's  from the USB on the TV and no buzz.  I suspect  the low power signal from the tv is an issue.

Comment: Added the speaker spec sheet to the question. As you said, aux goes from TV to sub, and then sub passes signal onto speakers.

Comment: That clarifies it, Thanks. That system is integrated so the speakers are getting their power from the the sub.  You have it hooked up properly. The LED's  may be causing interference or the aux cable is cheap and you may find a shielded one will help. Technically that is a computer sound set up, not sure if using it with a TV has any bearing on the problem.

Comment: The aux cable is integrated into the sub so I'm guessing its not the issue (i.e. not low quality)? Not sure I could replace it either way for that reason. If the LEDs are the issue, does it make sense that the interference goes away when the LEDs are on but plugged into a different power source?

Comment: My LED's  plug into the USB port on the tv.  Is everything grounded, I would try different outlets for all, see if you can effect changes.

Comment: The speaker and tv are plugged into different outlets. The LED lights are powered by USB, but it needs to be the TV USB so that the lights turn on/off with the TV (don't want the lights on when the TV is off)

Comment: It sounds like you may be overloading the USB port. The high pitch squeal is the switching supply trying to provide enough power but the caps are not large enough, I believe this is why it works when powered from another source.

Comment: @EdBeal any suggested solution to this?

Comment: I don’t know of any but possibly a usb controlled relay the relay drawing a very small current turns on and off the LED’s but uses a separate power supply similar to how you power them without the squeal. But I have not looked to see if such a premade device exists.

Comment: I looked online for a few minutes I saw a usb 1 Chanel delay timer for 7$ that timer could be set to zero and instead of having to push the button a jumper could be added so when the device powers up it pulls in the relay. Run the + voltage in one relay contact and out the other and that may just do the trick but just a guess I would guess it would draw less power and may do the trick if you are up to giving it a try, I think it was DZS delay timer.

Comment: Please post all make/model/specifications for all components involved in your question, not just the speakers. USB hosts are only required to provide 500 mA per connection; if your LEDs are pulling more than that, they are out of spec. Even if they are in spec, they could be feeding RF interference from their own switching power supply back through the USB power line, which the audio amplifier then picks up. Without more details, any answer is pure speculation.

Comment: FWIW, there are "powered USB hubs" that you could try, to either provide more power to the LEDs and/or isolate them from the TV, and _some_ might turn off the power if the host they are plugged into is also off. For sure, many do not and are powered all the time, which doesn't address your concern. But you could check around and see if you can find one that works like you want. It also would not be hard to home-brew a circuit that switches the separately-powered LEDs based on power from the TV USB, for someone that knows electronics.

Comment: I don't think the "cheap Chinese LEDs" have anything to do with this interference but the 110v that powers them is the issue. Electrical power and low voltage wiring should be kept at least a foot away or maybe more, as I recall. Without a picture I don't know if my thought is applicable, but putting the speaker wires into a conduit or raceway to shield them might help with the interference.

Answer (score 2):

Chances are that the the USB power and the AUX output of your TV share the same 5V power rail. When you connect the LEDs, you either overwork the power supply or some power modulation from the LEDs makes it's way through the power rails into your audio output.

One thing you could try to decouple the audio output by using a isolation transformer. Something like this perhaps [https://www.amazon.com/C2G-40000-Extension-Isolation-Transformer/dp/B0047AKVYO](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0047AKVYO) (no endorsement intended, illustration only) .

You should check that LEDs don't draw more power than what your TV USB output is rated for. That would be 2.5W for "old" USB and 4.5W for USB 3.0 and up. If your handy with electronic stuff, there are few things with capacitors and resistors you can try, but that would probably be a better fit for https://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Good answer.  IMO a TV USB port probably had little to no design thought given to its use as a power supply.  If it's so important to have TV back lighting synchronized with the TV I suggest you get a smart programmable remote or a wifi controller for the lights.  Then you can have them even better synced, like  disco effect for Jersey Shore, throbbing red for Housewives of Cleveland, and so on.